# negation of a null sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is null $\Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon >0, \exists X$ such that $$|a_n| < \epsilon  \ \forall n > X.$$
I want to give a definition when a sequence is not null, this is my approach, if $P_n(X) = |a_n| < \epsilon  \ \forall n > X$. Then, we have that:
$$\begin{align*}
\{a_n\} \ \mbox{is not null} \ \Leftrightarrow \neg[\forall \epsilon >0, \exists X P_n(X)] \\ 
 \Leftrightarrow \exists \epsilon >0 \ \neg \exists X P_n(X) \\ 
 \Leftrightarrow \exists \epsilon >0 \ \forall X \neg  P_n(X) 
\end{align*}$$
But I'm kinda confused on how to work out $\neg P_n(X)$. My attempt is the following: $$\begin{align*}
\neg P_n(X) \Rightarrow \neg[|a_n| < \epsilon  \ \forall n > X] \\ 
\neg P_n(X) \Rightarrow \exists n > X \ \mbox{with}\ |a_n| > \epsilon\\ 
\end{align*}$$
So, the whole statement would be
$$\exists \epsilon >0 \ \forall X [\exists n > X \ \mbox{with}\ |a_n| > \epsilon]$$

Is this correct and make sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your work is all correct. Except a minor issue: the opposite of $|a_n| < \epsilon$ is $|a_n| \ge \epsilon$, not $|a_n| > \epsilon$.

Instead of writing $P_n(X)$ as $|a_n| < \epsilon \; \forall n > X$, you may have found it clearer to write it as $\forall n > X \; |a_n| < \epsilon$. Then your entire statement would have been
$$
(\forall\epsilon > 0) \; (\exists X \in \mathbb{N}) \; (\forall n > X) \; : \; |a_n| < \epsilon
$$
which is very straightforward to negate, as you have done.

Some mathematicians have a habit of putting the quantifier ($\forall n$) after the statement in question, for instance they might say: 
"there exists $M$, such that $|a_n| < M$ for all $n$." The problem with such statements is that the syntax doesn't indicate whether they mean $\exists M \; \forall n \; |a_n| < M$, or $\forall n \; \exists M \; |a_n| < M$, which are two very different statements. You have to figure out where the $\forall n$ belongs from the context. In general I think this is a bad habit that should be avoided.

Comment: I think that there's no problem reordering the logical statement in text (as opposed to when dealing explicitly with formal logic).  Often, this reordering makes the statement easier to process (especially when there are a lot of consecutive $\forall$s or $\exists$s in a row).